# C#:"Unable to copy file... because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, build

Yes. my problem is very common in StackOverFlow, but I don't see the real solution for my problem yet, so I post again to hope some help for me.

I meet this error after each time I compile and run one project, and one compile and run again.

I just has one solution : open `Process Explorer` and kill A.exe (which A is a name of C# project).

But it is very handy, and I don't know why this very very stupid error and Microsoft hasn't fixed it, yet.

Thanks :)

Comment: How are you compiling? Are you simply doing `F5` which also _executes_ the startup project?

Comment: Or it could also be a very very stupid error in your code. If I were you I'd first try to work out which it is before attributing the blame to Microsoft.

Comment: You could help us to identify the problem by reducing your code to the simplest possible program that reproduces the error then posting that.

Comment: Why are you trying to build your project when the EXE is still running?  I'll put a buck on your code using DoEvents()

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, My EXE is still running, but because when I close my program, it just close (that I cannot see), but in real, it still run background, and I must open process explorer and handly delete it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile and run an executable, it is in use - that means that it *can't* be replaced by a recompile until the executable terminates.

If you application doesn't terminate, the executable file itself is in use. A recompile will attempt to replace that file and fail.

You need to ensure this happens before you can compile again.

Comment: You mean I must close program before (click x on the most right of form). So, as I say before, when I close window, it just invisible (mean no windows, no icon on taskbar,... as you have closed it). But in fact, this process still running background. And I must open process explorer to terminate it !!!

Comment: @hqt - Which means you are not terminating it correctly in your code.

Comment: Oh. thanks. I have understand your idea. Can you tell me more how to terminate correctly, please.

Comment: @hqt - Not without seeing your code. Do you handle the `Form.Close` event? Do you have `Application.Exit` anywhere?

Comment: Ah. Thanks so much :) I rarely do something like this on Java. I google and Form.Close() help me :D